# Find and run all scenarios where step is used?

Tags: visual-studio, specflow, test-explorer

I'm kinda new to SpecFlow but i would like to find and run all scenarios where step is used. I know about Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S option, but when it's used 20+ times on many feature files it can be hard to test it all one after another. This question came to my mind when i updated step and needed to retest it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a tag against the scenarios that contain that step - these will then appear within Test Explorer area if you filter based off 'Traits'. You can then run all scenarios with that tag.

So for example you would have

```
@TAGHERE
Scenario: Your Scenario
Given
When
Then
```